# Informix server is not able to start time to time

Tags: database, informix

I am trying to find the root cause of the issue with the Informix installation where the server is restarted every night (some legacy setup). Most of the restarts are OK, but from time to time the database does not start.
It ends just with the following lines:

```
...
Thu Dec 15 00:36:17 2022
 
00:36:17  Successfully added a bufferpool of page size 2K.
 
00:36:17  Event alarms enabled.  ALARMPROG = '/opt/IBM/informix/12.10/etc/alarmprogram.sh'
00:36:17  Booting Language <c> from module <>
00:36:17  Loading Module <CNULL>
00:36:17  Booting Language <builtin> from module <>
00:36:17  Loading Module <BUILTINNULL>
00:36:22  Entries in the surrogates file /etc/informix/allowed.surrogates are loaded into surrogate cache.
00:36:22  Trusted host cache successfully built:/etc/hosts.equiv.
00:36:22  DR: DRAUTO is 0 (Off)
00:36:22  DR: ENCRYPT_HDR is 0 (HDR encryption Disabled)
00:36:22  Event notification facility epoll enabled.
00:36:23  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC2WE Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
00:36:23  (5) connection rejected - no calls allowed for sqlexec
00:36:23  (6) connection rejected - no calls allowed for sqlexec
```

When I then SSH to the server, I am able to start it normally. Do you please have any idea what can cause this issue?
Thank you.

On the link bellow, there is a log from a successful start and from a failed on.

https://pastebin.com/hQPBccX6

Comment: My guess is informix is still starting and some connections get rejected because the server is not ready yet.  If you are stopping the server daily, make sure you use something like "onmode -kuy" to have a clean start later on. That should help with the start up.

Comment: Thanks, @jsagrera for your comment. I found additional information in /var/log/messages.
```norm kernel: [260664.025591] oncheck[4628]: segfault at 44120120 ip 0000000000537142 sp 00007fffad710920 error 4 in oncheck[400000+271000]```
Looks like something is corrupted on inside the VM.

Comment: @jsagrera I will also check scripts if there is the onmode -kuy called. Thank you once again.